# XAML Designer UI stop working and throw exception System.NotSupportedException in my WPF Application

Tags: c#, json, wpf, xaml, silverlight

Recently, while i was working on a project on wpf, i needed to get information from the web and parse it, so i used Json, i installed the package using  (Install-Package System.Json -Version 4.0.20126.16343), that worked great for me but when i wanted to open the xaml window it wont and an exception that look like this is thrown,

System.NotSupportedException
Le Kit de développement logiciel (SDK) Microsoft Silverlight 5.0 est introuvable. Vérifiez que la version appropriée du SDK a été installée.
   à Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   à Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOutSynchronous(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   à Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOut(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   à Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Action action, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode)
   à Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TResult,TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Func`2 func, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode)
   à Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.CreateDesignerImpl(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, RemoteCancellationToken remoteCancelToken)

Can anyone please tell me what to do to get ride of this exception,

note: when i delete the Json  reference the exception go away.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to use Newton.Json it's really reliable and efficient.

Comment: Can you tell me how to add it's reference

Comment: by nuget is easy, find Newton, in case you cannot tell me

Comment: ok thakn you it worked but now when i was using json.net i had this ligne code which was workin _result = JsonValue.Parse(webClient.DownloadString(fullUrl));
but now it isn't how can i make it work again with newton.json

Comment: var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json); where T is the type of the object of the json content.

Comment: and (json) can be replaced with what

Comment: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>( webClient.DownloadString(fullUrl));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probleme solved, by the help of Juan, i used Newton.json insteed of Json.net and it worked